# How do I update the dispatch.yaml file in Google App Engine to block POST requests, but allow GET?

Tags: google-app-engine

How do I update the dispatch.yaml file in Google App Engine to block POST requests, but allow GET?

I'm not sure if it's possible to allow/block method types?

Answer (score 2):

Don't believe that is possible.

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml), there are just 2 elements in a dispatch.yaml file - the url and the name of the service. There's no option to specify an http request method

Same documentation also says the file is just for routing